# Server overloaded by Apache

Tags: apache, drupal, load, webserver

On a dedicated server with Apache and MySQL we have a problem if traffic peeks over a certain number of request/min. In that case the server becomes totally unresponsive. The server is an Intel Dual-Core G6950 with 4GB RAM and on it is only one Drupal 6 site.

If Boost (static HTML caching method) is enabled the server keeps working just fine (load is close to nothing) with the same ammount of traffic so this is part of the solution. Even though I'd like to know how to configure the server so it won't go down even if caching is disabled for whatever reason or if the traffic goes up to a number where Apache will bring the server down again even with Boost enabled.

I found that with MaxClients set as low as 10 makes sure the server won't go down with Boost caching disabled but I read that it should be set to about 600 in this case (150 * ammound of RAM). This might be fine with Boost enabled but apparently not without it.

So long story short: I'm kind of lost. What can I do to make sure Apache won't break the entire server? I don't care if in extreme cases Apache can't serve all requests (with Boost enabled this won't happen anyway any time soon) but it should never ever become totally unresponsive just because it can't process requests fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

The optimal MaxClients value depends on the amount of memory available to Apache as well as the average memory per process. The value of 600 on a 4GB machine may be a bit too high because each process might take up to 25 MB or more, which would require 25MB x 600 = 15000MB of free memory. I'd try to be a bit more conservative in your case and set MaxClients to, say, 100-125.

Comment: Even a setting of 100 will eventually (read: within a minute) bring the server down without cache under a high load. With cache this would probably be ok but I want to make sure it also keeps responsive without it.

Comment: Are you sure it's Apache misbehaving and not, say, MySQL?

Comment: Could be, in that case i'd like to know more about that. Are there any good resources to get into it?